# C++-CLI tag does not format code like C++

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I noticed on a [C++/CLI question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858717/invalidoperationexception-throw-when-calling-xmlreaderreadstartelement), when I went to retag it as [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) and remove the bare [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, the highlighting for the code was no longer appropriate.

Could we have [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) automatically imply `lang-cpp` highlighting?