# Syntax coloring missing

Tags: support, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

[How do i random a number in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947617/how-do-i-random-a-number-in-a-string)

Any reason there's no coloring on the answers?

Answer (score 6):

Fixed it, I added a hint to the [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) indicating it should prettify with `c++` syntax.

Comment: So this is [status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100122/c-cli-tag-does-not-format-code-like-c)?

Comment: I guess .. I usually do not tag "support" stuff with status completed, however ... yeah it makes sense ... fixed

Answer (score 4):

[Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) must not be able to recognize C++/CLI code, and the [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) tag doesn't have any language associated with it, so it's forced to leave the code unhighlighted. The question has highlighting because someone [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7947617/4) to manually specify a language (they went with [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/90a99589-b75b-499f-a2e5-33471d7e9a35/view-source)), but the same would need to be done to the code blocks in each answer for highlighting to show up there. Alternatively, a moderator could set it so all [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) posts have C++ highlighting, if the syntax is close enough that that comes out right

Answer (score 2):

If you ever need to specify the language in the future, put this line before the code block (one line before and after it):

```
<!-- language: your-language -->
```

And for C++, it's `lang-c++`, I believe.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I didn't want everyone to have to do that...