# Coloring of source code not active

Tags: discussion

Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697014/projecting-a-3d-point-to-2d-screen-coordinate-opentk/12712672#12712672) of a post where the syntax coloring is missing. I've tried to follow the advice of manually adding the language definition from [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110669/syntax-coloring-missing) but to no avail.

Why does that happen and what can be done about it?

Comment: The correct syntax was just added.

Answer (score 5):

You wanted `<!-- language: lang-cpp -->`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Oh... I'm so retarded sometimes...  :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Thanks for taking the time to edit :)

Comment: Also - **HOW** did you rotate the characters in your name? It's like McDonald's - I'm loving it!

Comment: http://www.fliptext.org/

Comment: (˙˙˙ʇɐɥʇ ʞuıɥʇ oʇ ʎpɹǝu **os** ɯ,ı ɹo) ˙ןooɔ **os** sı sıɥʇ

Comment: But **HOW** is it done? There's not CSS for "upside-down", is there?!

Comment: It's possible with Unicode. But well, off-topic for here

Comment: @Chamster: By using unicode characters that look exactly like their ASCII counterparts but flipped. Paste the result into a unicode codepoint tool (such as [uniview](http://rishida.net/scripts/uniview/)) and marvel at the exotic codepoints!

Answer (score 2):

It has happened because the parser couldn't decide what language this is, so can't figure out what syntax highlighting algorithm to use.

The question is not tagged with a specific language - if it were tagged with the language, that would be a good hint for the highlighter.

There are also [highlight hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) that can be added.

Comment: The OP did add hints, just not correctly apparently.

Comment: I used the highling hint for C++ but the appearance didn't change. Maybe I did it wrong? I used the suggestion from the discussion I've posted a link to (might be the same as you had) and enter "C++" in the place of "your-language". It didn't work...

Comment: @Chamster - There is not `lang-C++` - it should have been `lang-cpp`. The parse is not that smart.